# Excel: How to extract ID number by looking up a persons first, middle and surname?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

hope you're well. I'm looking at extracting a person's ID by doing a partial VLOOKUP to their first, middle and surname in Excel, but not sure how to do so?

The problem with the data is that there might be some random text in the person's name which isn't applicable. I'm not sure how to show my sample data on here due to not being able to attach the worksheet on here, so hopefully it makes sense.

[image]

For example, my formula would pick up "UK property" as the first name, as of now the formula is:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(" ", A2)-1)
```

And the formula that I currently have to look up the ID only takes column A and any data afterwards as a partial VLOOKUP.

For example, my column E formula is currently:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&"*",'Data - FULL DUMP'!H1:$AE$46708,24,FALSE)
```

Data-full dump being the table it looks up to.

Perhaps I should have a formula that looks at the first, middle and surname individually and add "*" in between? (Not sure if this will work)

Formula doesn't bring back all the results.

Comment: There's an underlying problem here that is not directly related to Excel.  No matter the platform being used, trying to perform scripted decision-making based on non-normalized data is (a) profoundly difficult and (b) requires some subject matter expertise in the chosen scripting platform.  There's simply no way that an Excel function can correctly identify the desired first and last names in a cell like "UK Property Conor Lawson".  Automated lookups rely on data consistency as a prequisute.